# I have a file named "-t". How to remove it?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, rm

Output of "ls -l":

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Mar  4 08:22 -t
```

When i try to do "rm '-t'":

```
rm: invalid option -- 't'
Try 'rm ./-t' to remove the file '-t'.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Comment: So Try 'rm ./-t' to remove the file '-t'.

Comment: Did you read your own question at all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `rm -- -t` or `rm ./-t`

From `man rm`

```
To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo',
use one of these commands:

          rm -- -foo

          rm ./-foo
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find` too:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '-t' -delete
```

**Example:**

```
% ls 
egg -t

% find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '-t' -delete 

% ls
egg
```